# How to properly configure phonegap for Android so it does not zoom on text input

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meta

Good Morning All,

I am building an Android app and for the life of me I cannot stop HTC and ZTE devices from zoooming in ridiculously close when you use a text field.

I am trying to build this in a high resolution, and this is my meta viewport settings.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,target-densitydpi=320, initial-scale=1.0  minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

This works great on almost every single device, but on a test ZTE warp using 2.3.5 , it zooms into input fields.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the device, adding "user-scalable=no" to your viewtag might improve the situation. I would also try to remove the target-densitydpi for a test.

ALSO: I've just noted that your viewport string is actually incorrect. It misses a comma between initial-scale=1.0 and minimum-scale=1.0.

In addition, I'd recommend to remove all spaces. Some browsers are extremely picky when parsing the viewport information.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, the missing comma is not in my app, and the user-scalable=no is not a supported tag for these HTC/ZTE devices. This is not an issue with the Meta, its more an issue with the device, and was hoping to find a fix in phone gaps java.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap/Cordova apps use the built-in browser which ignores a lot of these meta-attributes, depending on the shipped version.

Phonegap recently added support for Androids windowSoftInputMode, which controls the behaviour of the soft keyboard.

Setting `<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />` in your config.xml disables zooming and uses panning instead.

For a comprehensive list of all possible values, see the Android API Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft