# Cordova: Leaflet Map Tiles disable transform to map pane

Tags: android, cordova, leaflet

When the app invokes the keyboard of the phone (when editing a text), map pane transforms, as shown in the image below:
[image]
What could be the reason, I added the map like this:

```
map = L.map('main').setView([9.123011560267038, 125.53513369515711], 15);
    L.tileLayer('./tile/cbr_new_design_tms2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: 14,
        maxZoom: 16,
        tms: true
    }).addTo(map);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel" id="main" style="padding:0;overflow:hidden" data-title="Main">
                <header>
                    <h1>Main</h1>
                    <a href="#modal1" class="button big icon question" style="float:right;padding-top:0;outline:0" data-transition="up-reveal"></a>
                    <a href="#modal" class="button big icon settings" style="padding-top:0;outline:0" data-transition="up-reveal"></a>
                </header>

            </div>
```

**Update:** I just noticed that when keyboard is invoke, leaflet adds `class="leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(XXpx, XXpx, XXpx);"`. It somehow transform the map pane. So, how do I prevent leaflet from transforming it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509121/leaflet-map-on-android-disrupted-by-appearance-of-keyboard

Comment: I'm using Cordova.

Comment: You can customize your Android manifest with Cordova as well. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833145/how-to-properly-configure-phonegap-for-android-so-it-does-not-zoom-on-text-input/27145959#27145959 and someone who just got the "opposite" problem as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627268/android-webview-keyboard-covering-up-input

Comment: Lots of config file: `intelxdk.config.android.xml` or `intelxdk.config.android.app`.

Comment: Learn how to use Cordova root `config.xml`

Comment: I'm unsing IntelXDK for Corodova App development.

Answer (score 0):

As @ghybs pointed out, there are Cordova configuration options which have a high chance of solving this.

Otherwise, if you can run ome javascript code when the user hides the keyboard, call the `invalidateSize()` method on the map instance.

Comment: I've tried both of yours and @ghybs suggestions, none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by commenting the `leaflet-src.js`:

```
_onResize: function () {
        L.Util.cancelAnimFrame(this._resizeRequest);
        this._resizeRequest = L.Util.requestAnimFrame(
                function () { this.invalidateSize({debounceMoveend: true}); }, this, false, this._container);
    },
```

Comment: For reference, if you want to disable Leaflet automatic adjustment when the window (in OP's case the WebView viewport size) is resized (in OP's case when the soft keyboard appears / disappears), just use the map's [`trackResize`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#map-trackresize) option instead of fiddling with a library source code.